# ConsoleAppender output redirection vs FileAppender

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there a difference between the performance between using a FileAppender vs a ConsoleAppender with a output redirection to a file?

Iniuitvely i suspect that FileAppender is faster because the ConsoleAppender has to "draw" first and then still write to the disk.

Can someone confirm my understanding?